# How to mock global variables defined in another file?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, unit-testing, jasmine

**mockData.js**

```
var userInfo = {
    URLs: {
        AppURL: "A" 
    },
    EncryptedBPC: "B"
};
```

**karma.config.js**

```
config.set({
    basePath: '',
    files:['mockData.js' ],
    .....
```

**ComponentDetailsComponent**:

```
.....some imports
import { ComponentDetailsService } from '../component-details.service';
declare var userInfo: any;
@Component({
    .....more code

    rfxFilter() {     
        return userInfo.URLs.AppURL;
    }
}
```

**Spec:**

```
describe('ComponentDetailsComponent', () => {
    let subject:any;
    let fixture: ComponentFixture<ComponentDetailsComponent>; 

    beforeEach(() => {
        TestBed.configureTestingModule({
            declarations: [ ComponentDetailsComponent ],
            providers: [{ provide: ComponentDetailsService, useClass: 
            ComponentDetailsServiceStub }],
        });
        fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ComponentDetailsComponent);
        subject = fixture.componentInstance;          
    });

    it('should return X', () => {
        subject.userInfo = {
            URLs: {
                AppURL: "X"
            },
            EncryptedBPC: "Y"
        };
        let result = subject.rfxFilter();
        expect(result).toBe("X");
    });   
});
```

**Output:**

> ReferenceError: userInfo is not defined

I have made it work by creating a method inside the component which will return userInfo global variable.

```
getuserInfo():any{
    return userInfo;
}
```

**And mocking that method in spec:**

```
let m = {
    URLs: {
        AppURL: "mockvalueAppURL",
    },
    EncryptedBPC: "mockEncryptedBPC",
};
let spy = spyOn(subject, 'getuserInfo').and.returnValue(m);
```

Is it not possible to mock such global variables without having to encapsulate it within methods and then mocking the method instead of variable? I would like to keep the application code untouched when written by somebody else.

Comment: Have you tried using behaviorSubject or replaySubject to have global data? This would let you subscribe it from anywhere and the it mocking it is same as mocking any subscription.

Comment: @Ankit It's an existing code by somebody else. I am just writing unit tests for that code . I don't want to make any changed in the code itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can't access any variables of any other files. You can't mock imports either. Your best friend is DI, as you can provide mock class in place of original for testing.

You will have to mock the service that provides the data, not having the data in a separate file. The only way would be to export JSON, or object and use the exported object.

```
TestBed.configureTestingModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [
        ComponentDetailsComponent,
    ],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: RealService,
            useExisting: StubService,
        },
    ],
}).compileComponents();
```

And implement the stub as this.

```
class StubService implements Partial<RealService> {
    getuserInfo() {
        return { ...mockedData };
    }
}
```

Note:

If you are dealing with mocking HTTP calls use `HttpTestingController`.

Comment: are you saying that it is not possible to mock this variable `userInfo` unless I get it's value from a separate service or a method withing the component?

Comment: @Arbaaz Exactly. But also that is doesn't seem right to access it, if you have stub, the stub should have the data and if you need to share it across multiple, expose the variable in a separate file that will be imported in these stubs.